# "This NSLayoutConstraint is being configured with a constant that exceeds internal limits"

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, breakpoints, lldb

While trying to debug an AutoLayout problem (a table cell which should be growing according to the size of its content isn't, in some circumstances), I set a breakpoint on the last line of my `tableView:heightForRow:` method, and trying to print the value of `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` I get this:

```
(lldb) p ((CGSize)[cachedCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize]).height
2014-10-14 11:15:49.492 AppName[72132:10302054] This NSLayoutConstraint is being configured with a constant that exceeds internal limits.  A smaller value will be substituted, but this problem should be fixed. Break on void _NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit() to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future.
(CGFloat) $0 = 57
```

Well ok, that's interesting. But I try and do what it says and set a breakpoint on that function:

[image: Grab of breakpoint definition on _NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit()]

... and this breakpoint doesn't get hit.

- Am I setting the breakpoint correctly?
- In any case, any clues on what might be wrong with my constraints to lead to this?

(Annoyingly, it seems to work in *some* cases but not in others and I can't see a difference in the setup.)

Comment: In my case using `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude` in constraints  was causing the problem

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Omit the `()` from the symbol name.  It's a little clearer what is happening if you use the debugger console window to set this breakpoint with the `breakpoint set --name` command:

```
(lldb) br s -n _NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit()
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
(lldb) br s -n _NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit
Breakpoint 2: where = Foundation`_NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit, address = 0x00007fff9168e6f5
(lldb)
```

If you had used the `breakpoint list` (`br l`) command in your Xcode debug session, you would have seen that the `_NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit()` breakpoint didn't get set in any locations.

Comment: Well, now I've got a breakpoint set according to `br l` (thank you!) but it still doesn't get hit—unless I call `p (CGSize)[cachedCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize]` in the debugger, in which case I can see the hit count go up!

Comment: Finally solved the problem. If I have to set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` on the label manually, what the hell is Auto Layout doing for me?!

Comment: @RobertAtkins, how did you fix it?

Comment: I had a label horizontally adjacent to a UIImageView in my cell. In order for the label to correctly calculate the height it wanted, I had to set its `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to the width of the cell, minus the width of the UIImageView and any adjacent padding. That I had to do this at all I find kind of stupid, and it seems it's no longer necessary on iOS 8.

Comment: @RobertAtkins,  looks really stupid. What in case of different cell width?

Comment: I think I subtracted the UIView & padding from the cell's contentView.frame.width? Don't have that code to hand right now.